# Ошибка pointer being freed was not allocated при завершении программы

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

При перегрузке оператора + выдает такую ошибку, как её можно пофиксить?

second laboratory(25641,0x1003b4380) malloc: *** error for object 0x102801650: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Конструктор

```
list(){
    arr = new Programmist[6];
    capacity = 7;
    count =0;
}
```

Деструктор

```
~list(){
    if (arr != NULL) delete[] arr;
    arr = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
```

Перегрузка операторов

```
list operator +(list& lst,Pro* node){
   lst.onlyadd(node);
   return lst;
}

list operator +(Pro* node, list& lst){
   lst.onlyadd(node);
   return lst;
}
```

Проверка перегрузки

```
int main(){
   list program;
   Pro* node =new Pro;
   Pro* nodet(node);
   program._getin(nodet);
   program = nodet + program;
   return 0;
}
```

В гугле я ничего не смог найти, подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так

Comment: Не надо нарезать код на кусочки, лучше сразу приводите [mcve].

Comment: Вангую, что дело в нарушении [правила трех](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Скорее всего не хватает соблюдения [правила трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)). Ну и проверки на `nullptr` при `delete`, а уж тем более обнуление (члена?) `arr` не нужны.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в следующий раз учту

Comment: @älёxölüt а почему обнуление не нужно, я просто не особо понимаю?

Comment: А для чего оно нужно? Объект уничтожается, все его члены тоже. Кто будет проверять нуль там или не нуль?

Comment: @älёxölüt а можете направить в правильное русло, как будет более правильно сделать проверку на  `nullptr`?

Comment: @walde правильно вообще не проверять в данном случае, вызывать `delete` или `delete[]` c `nullptr` безопасно.

Comment: @Slava вот так сделать
`~list(){
    delete[] arr;
  }`?

Comment: Да, но еще лучше использовать `std::vector` или хотябы умные указатели. Это если пишете реальные программы, если делаете домашнее задание, то ручное управление памятью возможно требуется преподавателем для понимания предмета. Учтите исправление деструктора не исправит ошибку, это просто пожелание. Проблема в генерируемом компилятором конструкторе копии - смотрите правило трех на которое уже указали два раза.

Comment: Нет оператора присваивания, автоматически генерируемый выполняет поверхностное копирование... Результат - двойное освобождение (и утечка :))

Comment: @Harry что именно нужно присваивать?

Comment: Ну оператор `list::operator=(const list&)`, который будет копировать массив, а не указатель на него...